# Как сделать анимированное изменение размера элемента на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Нужно элементу задать `transform: scale(2)` с анимацией.
Делаю так, но не работает.

```
$(".js-active_icon").animate({"transform": "scale(2)"}, 500);
```

Как правильно сделать анимацию?

Comment: Насколько я помню, то jQuery не может анимировать нечисловые свойства CSS. Используйте добавление класса с нужными CSS-анимациями.

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так написать.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(2)');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```